# EF Core 6.0 onModelCreating running when running ASP.NET Core Application (outside the Migration)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have an application written in ASP.NET Core using .NET 6.0.7. And I have generated migrations and applied them to the database using `database-update` manually - or for production we are using the `ef bundle` to update the database.

This being said I am using `HasData` to seed initial data. This is achieved inside the `OnModelCreating` method in the `DbContext`. And whenever any of the seed data changes I cover this with a new migration.

**NOTE**: I do not have any migration code in the `program.cs` for the ASP.NET Core Web API code, but it seems that during debugging (and on production), `OnModelCreating` is still called - WHY?

There should be no reason to run `OnModelCreating` when in debug or production when starting up the Web API. Is this an error in EF Core? Or am I seriously missing something?

Answer (score 3):

`OnModelCreating` supposed to run every time, this is normal.

> In EF Core, seeding data can be associated with an entity type as part
> of the model configuration. Then EF Core migrations can automatically
> compute what insert, update or delete operations need to be applied
> when upgrading the database to a new version of the model.

You should only use `HasData` if you want migrations to manage applying changes to it, otherwise just add it to the database using `SaveChanges` when needed.

For more details, see [Creating and configuring a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) and [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

Comment: But I don't understand - Hasdata is included when doing a migration and therefore these are managed correctly (in our case) using efBundle's. This being the case and we manage these migrations as required. Why would the asp.net WebApi need to run through the AsModelCreating during startup of the Application?  
This just plain doesn't make sense ???

Comment: In my opinion, this is because EF attempts to validate the Database state, before performing migrations. That validation appears to demand a model for comparison, thus the method is run.